# What is this gourd-like vegetable?

Tags: food-identification, indian-cuisine

I don't know the name of the fruit in English and hence I'm attaching the figure if it.

[image]

I don't know the exact name of the vegetable. But I'm guessing the following names: sponge gourd, luffa cylindrica, luffa.

What is the exact name of the fruit?

Comment: foods have different names in different countries, so it would help if you included your location

Answer (score 2):

Going by your guesses, I found the following names on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luffa_aegyptiaca) (all for the same plant): sponge gourd, Egyptian cucumber, Vietnamese luffa, dishrag gourd, rag gourd, vegetable-sponge or smooth luffa. Its Latin names are Cucurbita luffa, Luffa cylindrica, Luffa aegyptica, Luffa aegyptiaca, Luffa pentandra, Momordica cylindrica. or Momordica luffa.

I am not completely sure if the plant in the photo is the plant on the Wikipedia page. However, the Wiki has a translations in many different languages, so perhaps you can look for one in a language in which you know the plant's name?

**Edit:** Given your updated tag of `Indian`, I should point out there are Wikipedia pages for the vegetable I linked to in [Hindi](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%98%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%BC%E0%A4%BE), [Marathi](https://mr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%98%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B3%E0%A5%87) and [Tamil](https://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%80%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%81) as well as 28 more languages.